# Hangfire keeps running recurring jobs late

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

So I have several recurring jobs that are supposed to run on a certain hour:

```
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Runner.SendTestEmail(), Cron.Daily, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Runner.CleanProjectFiles(), "0 0 * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Runner.IPAudit(), Cron.Daily, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

These are all supposed to run at midnight, however they are running at all times of the day.

The last time all of my midnight jobs ran was at 5:13 AM.

I checked the time and timezone of the box hosting the site, I set the QueuePollInterval to 15 seconds but things are still running several hours late.

The SQL box is different from the box hosting the site, however I made sure to check the time there as well to make sure that everything was the same.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could fix this issue?

Is there something I have to configure in IIS?

Comment: Is your app pool set to recycle with no traffic? With Hangfire, if a tree is scheduled to fall in the forest, it will wait to make a sound until there's someone to hear it, so to speak. The app pool needs to be alive for Hangfire to run.

Comment: Cool, will give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you UtopiaLtd, your answer worked perfectly.

> Is your app pool set to recycle with no traffic? With Hangfire, if a tree is scheduled to fall in the forest, it will wait to make a sound until there's someone to hear it, so to speak. The app pool needs to be alive for Hangfire to run